# Unable to get data on press

Tags: react-native

Unable to get data in onPress but it is showing data in view how?

Trying to get item.cash *console.log(item.cash)* getting value 0
but in view it is 500.

Very new to react native please help me to understand data flow.

```
 _renderItem({item, index}, parallaxProps) {
          const { rewardRedemptions } = reference.RewardRedemptionReducer;

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            var cashAmt = parseInt(item.cash);
            if (cashAmt == 0) {
                return;
            }

      **console.log(item.cash);
      console.log(parseInt(item.cash));**
          >

                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: Dimens.twentyThree,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: Fonts.SourceSansProSemibold,
                  }}
                  *children={item.cash}*
                </...>
        );
      }
```

Comment: Where is the onPress ?

Comment: sorry, edited now you can see btw it fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 _renderItem({item, index}, parallaxProps) {
      const { rewardRedemptions } = reference.RewardRedemptionReducer;
    **console.log(item.cash);
    console.log(parseInt(item.cash));**

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={()=>console.log(parseInt(item.cash))} ---> try this
      >

            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: Dimens.twentyThree,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: Fonts.SourceSansProSemibold,
              }}
              *children={item.cash}*
            </...>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks , it works when placed inside return statement